# Template function to execute member callback on templated object without providing it's instance

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, callback, stdbind

Some context...

- I have a map containing vectors of objects as values.
- Each vector contains objects of specialized type.
- The keys of the maps are the values of an enum representing each types, `EnumObjType`
- I am receiving events containing an `EnumObjType` and an `ObjID`.

I am trying to build a template function to process any type of object, and my challenge is that these objects IDs are accessed with methods of the specialized class. To work around that, I am trying to add a parameter to my template function that would be the function to be called to get the `SpecializedObj`'s ID.

The template function call looks like this :

```
bool processEvent<SpecializedObj>(iEvent, iObjMap, &SpecializedObj::getSpecializedId);
```

The definition :

```
template<typename ObjType>
bool processEvent(MyEvent* iEvent,  ObjMap* iObjMap, std::function<unsigned int(void)> iObjIdCall)
{
  // Reach the corresponding ObjType vector
  ObjMap::iterator it =  iObjMap->find(iEvent->getObjType());
  std::vector<BaseObject*> wObjVector = it->second;

  // Iterate over the vector's range  
  for(BaseObject* wBaseObjPtr : wObjVector)
  {
    // Cast into SpecializedObj
    ObjType* wSpecializedObjPtr = dynamic_cast<ObjType*>(wBaseObjPtr);

    // Test dynamic_cast result
    if(!wSpecializedObjPtr) {return false;}

    std::function<unsigned int(void)> callback = std::bind(iObjIdCall,*wSpecializedObjPtr);

    // Check if the SpecializedObjPtr's ID matches the event's DeviceId
    if(callback() != iEvent->getDeviceId()) {return false;}

    // work on SpecializedObj
    // ...
    return true
  }
```

And below the rather cryptic error to my eyes:

```
11>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(514) : error C2664: 'std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Set' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Rx> *'
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int
11>        ]
11>        and
11>        [
11>            _Rx=const unsigned int
11>        ]
11>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const &)(void) const,_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>>,
11>            _Fty=const unsigned int (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const &)(void) const
11>        ]
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Do_alloc<_Myimpl,_Fret(__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const &)(void) const,_Alloc>(_Fty,_Alloc)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>>,
11>            _Fty=const unsigned int (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const &)(void) const
11>        ]
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,SpecializedObj,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_Fret (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const )(void) const,_Alloc)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Ty=std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>,
11>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>>
11>        ]
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(514) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Reset_alloc<_Fret,SpecializedObj,std::allocator<_Ty>>(_Fret (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const )(void) const,_Alloc)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Ty=std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>,
11>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_Func_class<const unsigned int>>
11>        ]
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Reset<const unsigned int,SpecializedObj>(_Fret (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const )(void) const)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int
11>        ]
11>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\functional(675) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret>::_Reset<const unsigned int,SpecializedObj>(_Fret (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* const )(void) const)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Ret=const unsigned int,
11>            _Fret=const unsigned int
11>        ]
11>        C:\MyProject\ObjUpdater.cpp(29) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>::function<const unsigned int(__thiscall SpecializedObj::* )(void) const>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Fty=const unsigned int (void),
11>            _Fx=const unsigned int (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* )(void) const
11>        ]
11>        C:\MyProject\ObjUpdater.cpp(29) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<_Fty>::function<const unsigned int(__thiscall SpecializedObj::* )(void) const>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
11>        with
11>        [
11>            _Fty=const unsigned int (void),
11>            _Fx=const unsigned int (__thiscall SpecializedObj::* )(void) const
11>        ]
```

When I had previously worked with callbacks, I always knew with what object instance it would be associated, so I'd pass it as function parameters with `std::bind(&Foo::func, fooObj)` but it does not seem to work for me here.

EDIT:
I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 v110 toolset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I had previously worked with callbacks, I always knew with what object instance it would be associated, so I'd pass it as function parameters with `std::bind(&Foo::func, fooObj)` but it does not seem to work for me here.

If `processEvent()` receive `iObjIdCall` as a `std::function<unsigned int(void)>`, when you try to bind it and saving the `std::bind()` result in an object of the same type

```
std::function<unsigned int(void)> callback
    = std::bind(iObjIdCall,*wSpecializedObjPtr);
```

you confuse the compiler.

Try defining `processEvent()` as receiving a pointer to method instead of a `std::function`; something as

```
template <typename ObjType>
bool processEvent (MyEvent* iEvent,  ObjMap* iObjMap, ObjType::*iObjIdCall)
```

if I remember correctly the syntax.

Comment: @ max66 Following your advice, I got it to compile with the following template declaration `bool processEvent (MyEvent* iEvent,  ObjMap* iObjMap, const unsigned int (ObjType::*iObjIdCall)(void)) const` and with the following callback in the function : `if((wSpecializedObjPtr->*iObjIdCall)() != iEvent->getDeviceId())`

I'm not certain to understand what is confusing to the compiler though... would you care to elaborate a little?

Comment: @VincentDM - Isn't completely clear to me to; the point is that passing `&SpecializedObj::getSpecializedId` to a `std::function<unsigned int(void)>` you make somethig wrong because the resulting object should be callable without arguments and it isn't; then, when you use `std::bind()`... well... bind what with a `std::function` expecting nothing (`void`)?